# What framework to use play videos like in applications like YouTube and Instagram IOS

Tags: ios, swift, video-streaming, streaming

I'm trying to build a social media app where you can play upload videos to a database
And then can be streamed and played like you can on YouTube and Instagram

my question is in applications like YouTube and Instagram
what frameworks are used if anyone knows this for example is it AV foundation or any other frameworks or techniques that I'm not aware off

apologies if this is not the right place to ask this question but I'm very new to iOS and Swift and finding a hard time to get information from other people.

I know how to use AV foundation but just wanted to know was this still the correct way to do it

Comment: You can use YouTube api

Comment: To play videos on iOS use AV Foundation. Don't worry how others do it (could be C++ code, etc). You need a license to decode patented video formats like MP4 and here Apple already got the license for the Swift language and its coders.

Comment: thank you for the feedback I appreciate it